# Windows version not showing

Tags: windows, version

I've got a quite strange problem (I think). My windows version (I'm running windows 7 Home Premium) is not showing when I go to see system preferences. I've installed a windows 8 skin, can this be the problem, and how can I fix it? (don't want to delete the skin though).

Hope you can help, thanks :-)

Comment: What does "Control Panel -> System and Security -> System" show?

Comment: It shows all the information it should, except the top collum saying "Windows version" wich is blank :(. How can I fix this??

Answer (score 2):

just go to your command prompt (via start menu) and type the following command:

winver

This will display the windows version and details

Alternatively you can run the same command from Start->Run

Comment: thanks, my problem is'nt really knowing what windows version I'm running, it's more that I can't see it under system preferences that annoys me :(